# Creating a Dynamic List with a href using JS on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone help me create a Dynamic List with Href.. I only know how to add a list but I don't know how to add links for every list

```
<h1>Toppings</h1>
<ul>
 
</ul>
<script>
var toppings = ['tomatoes', 'olives', 'cheese', 'peperonies']
</script>
```

Now i want to have a dynamic list with links not just list. Can someone help me.

Comment: toppings.forEach(function(topping) { [append the link to the ul] });

Comment: just noticed this code isn't working... just found that on kirupa website... can someone create a new code..

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on forming questions in a way that will best enable the community to provide you with useful assistance.  Generally, it is expected that you will show your attempt at solving your problem and explain any problems you are encountering.  Critically, please note that SO is not a free coding service-- it is unlikely you will get much response for a post simply requesting somebody write an entire code solution for you.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an anchor tag inside a list item for each topping and append it to your unordered list

```html
<h1>
    Toppings
</h1>
<ul id="toppings-list">

</ul>
<script>
    let toppings = ['tomatoes', 'olives', 'cheese', 'peperonies'];
    const toppingsList = document.querySelector('#toppings-list');

    toppings.forEach(topping => {
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', topping);
        link.innerText = topping;

        listItem.appendChild(link);
        toppingsList.appendChild(listItem);
    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is with the [.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) methods.

**Edit:**
Inserting links depends on where you want the links to go (of course) but the snippet now includes a crude demonstration of dynamically creating anchor elements related to each list item.

```js
const toppings = ['tomatoes', 'olives', 'cheese'];
const myUl = document.getElementById("my-ul");

for(let topping of toppings){
  const newLi = document.createElement("li");
  const newAnchor = document.createElement("a");
  newAnchor.href = "#" + topping;
  newAnchor.textContent = topping;
  newLi.appendChild(newAnchor);  
  myUl.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```html
<h1>Toppings</h1>
<ul id="my-ul"></ul>

<div>-</div><div>-</div><div>-</div>
<div id="tomatoes">tomatoes target</div>

<div>-</div><div>-</div><div>-</div>
<div id="olives">olives target</div>

<div>-</div><div>-</div><div>-</div>
<div id="cheese">cheese target</div>

<div>-</div><div>-</div><div>-</div>
<div>-</div><div>-</div><div>-</div>
<div>-</div><div>-</div><div>-</div>
<div>-</div><div>-</div><div>-</div>
<div>-</div><div>-</div><div>-</div>
```

Comment: so to create a dynamic list i should use this but how to add href to it like li tag + href + (name or something)